# To increase a button's size when it is pressed in Android

Tags: android, button, size, pressed

How can I make my button's size to increase slightly when it is pressed and decrease again when it is released? This is for highlighting the pressed button, by using size in addition to a different color.

Regards,
Kiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `Button` a field, and modify its size in the `OnTouchListener` associated with it. Using an OnTouchListener you can listen for different `MotionEvents`, such as `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

Answer (score 2):

Since API 21 (Lollipop) an xml-only solution is available based on the [stateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator) attribute. Even though its primary goal to animate view properties based on state changes you can disable the animation if it's required by setting `duration="0"`. For example:

```xml
<!-- res/layout/my_layout.xml -->

<LinearLayout ...
  android:stateListAnimator="@animator/zoom_animator">...</layout>
```

```xml
<!-- res/animator/zoom_animator -->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <set>
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="scaleX" android:valueTo="1.0" android:duration="0" />
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="scaleY" android:valueTo="1.0" android:duration="0" />
    </set>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="scaleX" android:valueTo="1.1" android:duration="0" />
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="scaleY" android:valueTo="1.1" android:duration="0" />
    </set>
  </item>
</selector>
```

There's also two similar questions about animated scale:

- [Animatedly reduce button size on press and regain it's size on release](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37318133/4858777)
- [Android scale button on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38474593/4858777)

Comment: this first link has the best solution

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples

Comment: This answer does not work at my project until I add `android:state_pressed="false"` in the default item.

Answer (score 1):

```java
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

        //Code to convert height and width in dp.
        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 140, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            layoutParams.width = width + 5;
            layoutParams.height = height + 5;
            SearchButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            layoutParams.width = width;
            layoutParams.height = height;
            SearchButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In your activity

```
Private Button myButton;

//...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//...

myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    _button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myButton.setWidth(50);
        myButton.setHeight(50);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: But my issue is to increase button size when pressed and get back to normal size when button is released.

Comment: use an ontouch listener then. in that u need to define Motionevent.On actiion up. On action down. etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try it

Private Button myButton;

//...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//...

myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    _button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myButton.setWidth(myButton.getWidth()+5);
        myButton.setHeight(myButton.getHeight()+5);
        }
      });
    }
```