# I want to increase size of text in edit text when I press plus button and decrese when I press minus button

Tags: android

Here I put my code of 2 buttons.

I have to face one problem.  Button works OK in MDPI view but I have a problem in the QVGA emulator.

In QVGA when I press the `plus` button then its size decreases y and when I press the `minus` button, no change occurs

```
if(v==im7)
{
    float size=tx3.getTextSize();
    float size1=tx2.getTextSize();

    Toast.makeText(this,"plus"+String.valueOf(size),2000).show();

    size=size+1;
    size1=size1+1;

    tx3.setTextSize(size);
    tx2.setTextSize(size1);                 
}

if(v==im8)
{
    /*float size=tx3.getTextSize();
    float size1=tx2.getTextSize();
    */
    Toast.makeText(this,"minus"+String.valueOf(size),2000).show();

    size=size-1;
    size1=size1-1;

    tx3.setTextSize(size);
    tx2.setTextSize(size1);         
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778401/to-increase-a-buttons-size-when-it-is-pressed-in-android

Comment: @Adinia I don't think it's a duplicate as the one you linked to is about button size.

Comment: @dave.c Indeed, seems like you are right; I didn't read too carefully :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will probably only work for mdpi screens. mdpi are the standard but ldpi and hdpi are scaled at 0.75% and 1.5% respectively.

Try this:

In your instance variables:

```
private DisplayMetrics metrics;
private int my_density;
private TextView your_textview;
```

In your onCreate, initialize your variables and find your view and set its onclicklistner (make sure to implement OnClickListener):

```
your_textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_your_textview);
your_textview.setOnClickListener(this);
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
my_density = metrics.densityDpi;
```

Then the tricky part:

Depending on the screen density you need to scale the size you give setTextSize() accordingly. Really setTextSize() should take care of this but it doesn't. Use the method below as an example of how to increase the text for your TextView.

```
private void increaseFontSize(){
        float size = your_textview.getTextSize();
        int max_size = 30; //define your own max here
        if(size<=max_size){
            switch(my_density){
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                size = (your_textview.getTextSize()+2) / 0.75f;
                break;

            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                size = your_textview.getTextSize()+2;
                break;

            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                size = (your_textview.getTextSize()+2) / 1.5f;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            your_textview.setTextSize(size);
            your_textview.invalidate();

        }
        else{
            //beyond limit, don't do anything
        }
    }
```

Now in your onclick just call the method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()) {

    case(R.id.txt_your_textview):
        increaseFontSize();
        break;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to increase and decrease size of text in a text box.. OK just follow this example..

```
Textview v= new Textview();

onButtonClickEvent()
{
    v.setTextSize(v.getTextSize()+5);
}
```

Comment: the question is about changing the size of text, not the size of a text box.

Comment: @dave.c  i had changed my answer.ok??