# ImageButton back to previous .xml

Tags: android, xml, button

i am trying to create  button that when pressed changes state for example a virtual bin button that has an initial image of a bin then when pressed in the image changes to a bin with an open lid. So far i have a selector linked to a seperate xml in drawable with the three states, but when it clicks in it doesn't stay on the "in clicked" state, it just clicks on and off, do i need to change it from an imagebutton to a toggle or something, also the button size doesnt change, i need it to change to smaller size when clicked on, i hope this makese sense, here is my code, thanks :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/sunday_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sunday_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sunday_default" />
</selector>
```

The xml with the button :

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sun"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mon"
    android:background="@drawable/vpbuttons"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sunday"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

the java :

```
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sun);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

}
}
```

Would i be better of somehow creating an interactive graphic rather then a button? if so is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a button to "toggle" to a different state in between clicks, then you'd want to subclass `ToggleButton`.  You should be able to use your selector just fine.  To modify the size of the button on click, you can do that in code in the `onClick()` method.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778401/to-increase-a-buttons-size-when-it-is-pressed-in-android), mentions increasing size when clicked.

Comment: Ok, righto thanks, when changing the button size is there any way to specify the alignment? so rather than it change shape to the centre it changes shape and places at the top of the original button?

Comment: How drastically are you changing your button's size?