# Android scale button on touch

Tags: android, button, timer, scale, ontouchlistener

I know how to scale the button to a determinated value, but is there a way to increase/decrease the button size per time as long the user is touching it?
Something like this:

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Some timer action here or is there a better way?
                v.setScaleX(v.getScaleX() + 0.1f);
                v.setScaleY(v.getScaleY() + 0.1f);
                return true;
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.setScaleX(1);
                v.setScaleY(1);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Other Idea - doesn't work:

```
    myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      myButton.setScaleX(myButton.getScaleX() + 0.1f);
                      myButton.setScaleY(myButton.getScaleY() + 0.1f);
                    }
                };
                while(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ //Seems to be an infinite loop
                    timer.schedule(timerTask, 100);
                }

            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.setScaleX(1);
                v.setScaleY(1);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

And is there a way to do the whole thing with xml (drawable and animations)?

Comment: [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm) is a very good example for what you are trying to achieve. Instead of imageview in the tutorial, you can animate your button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animatedly reduce button size on press and regain it's size on release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318133/animatedly-reduce-button-size-on-press-and-regain-its-size-on-release)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    int action = motionEvent.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        v.animate().scaleXBy(100f).setDuration(5000).start();
        v.animate().scaleYBy(100f).setDuration(5000).start();
        return true;
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        v.animate().cancel();
        v.animate().scaleX(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
        v.animate().scaleY(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This should do the trick ;)

Comment: this works ok, but you have to move your finger while touching the button to increase the size.

Comment: I edited my answer. Give it a try and let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: There we go, that's it!

Comment: My issue with this is if you slide your finger off the view and release it, the view will be stuck in the down state.

Comment: it is nice to cancel animation when MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL too

Answer (score 1):

Since API 21 (Lollipop) an xml-only solution is available based on the [stateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator) attribute. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911493/4858777) of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37318133/4858777) for an example.